# De-normalizing Google Trends data?

Tags: time-series, dataset, descriptive-statistics

Does anybody have suggestions on how to de-normalize Google Trends data? The site says that their trends are made with the following metric:

> The numbers on the graph reflect how many searches have been done for a particular term, relative to the total number of searches done on Google over time. They don't represent absolute search volume numbers, because the data is normalized and presented on a scale from 0-100. Each point on the graph is divided by the highest point and multiplied by 100. When we don't have enough data, 0 is shown

I've been trying to work backwards from there but realized I need the peak value for each search query, which I don't have. Any thoughts appreciated.

Here's an example Google Trends search: http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=stack%20exchange&cmpt=q&tz=

Comment: I wonder if this question does not suite better for http://opendata.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: I don't think it fits opendata. It's a simple question about a normalization strategy, but unfortunately there is any solution if you don't know the maximal value of the search volume array!

Comment: I have a paper related to denormalization of Google Trends' indices here: https://www.jmir.org/2020/1/e13347/ The short tutorial on denormalization is here: https://www.slideshare.net/ShahanAliMemon/google-trends-denormalized-175072435

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the normalization consists in
$$ \mathbf{z} = \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\max(\mathbf{x})}, $$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector of search volumes, and $\max(\mathbf{x})$ is the maximal element of $\mathbf{x}$, if you want de-normalized data, you should multiply each element of the normalized vector times the maximal element of $\mathbf{x}$:

$$ \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{z} \times \max(\mathbf{x}). $$

Unfortunately, if you don't know the value of $\max(\mathbf{x})$ you can't de-normalize your data.

Comment: Google AdWords provide monthly keyword search volumes. Might be useful a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

De-normalizing Google Trends data can be very useful, but it is tricky, due to rounding errors: when comparing 2 queries of vastly different search volume, the time series for the less frequent query could appear to be 0 everywhere.

To solve this problem, we have developed a method called *Google Trends Anchor Bank.* It's available here: https://github.com/epfl-dlab/GoogleTrendsAnchorBank

A technical paper describing the method is available here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.13861